# Update image on specific UITableViewCell after launching camera from that UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`, each cell contains a `UIImageView` and a `UIButton`. I launch the camera once the button is tapped and I am trying to update the `UIImageView` in the index path for that cell. This is what I have tried so far but the images are not updating:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var objects = ["cup", "phone", "shoe", "tv"]
var images = [UIImage?](repeating:nil, count: 4)
var imageTaken : UIImage!
var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController?
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func TakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker!.sourceType = .camera
    present(imagePicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    images[sender.tag] = imageTaken
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.buttonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.buttonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.TakePhoto(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.imageFound.image = images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        self.imageTaken = pickedImage

    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
} 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker?.delegate = self
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of define `self.imageTaken` as `UIImage` you need keep reference of your indexPath.row selected when `UIImagePickerController` is presented and in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method then pass the image in your images array according that `indexPath.row`

**something like this**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var objects = ["cup", "phone", "shoe", "tv"]
var images = [UIImage?](repeating:nil, count: 4)
var currentRow : Int = -1
var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController?
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func TakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker!.sourceType = .camera
    self.currentRow = sender.tag
    present(imagePicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.buttonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.buttonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.TakePhoto(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.imageFound.image = images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        guard self.currentRow != -1 else{ 
            return
        }

        images[self.currentRow] = pickedImage
        self.currentRow = -1
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
} 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker?.delegate = self
}
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! Only question, what does that guard statment do?

Comment: guard ensure that some preconditions are meet before continue code execution if those conditions are not meet then the else block is executed in this case the condition is `self.currentRow != -1` because if is -1 we don't want to do anything and must be an error in fact

Comment: @mikew i suggest you google it, is very a useful tool